# override in multilevel inheritance with intermediate derived class not having the function overriden

Tags: c++, c++03

In multilevel inheritance, can I override a virtual function in a base class later down in the hierarchy of the inheritance? For an examplem

```
class Base {
public : 
virtual void method1();

///
}

class Derived1 : Base {
public : 
void method2();
}

class Derived2 : Derived1 {
public :
void method1();
}
```

is it possible for me to access the Derived2::method1() using polymorphism?

```
Base* myClass = new Derived2();

myClass->method1();
```

Comment: Yes. But Have you tried ? Have you a problem with it ?

Comment: and add `override` on the overriden virtual methods.

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher I don't use c++11 yet :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once a parent class have marked a function as `virtual`, that "virtualness" stays. It doesn't matter how many levels of inheritance you have or if any intermediate classes doesn't override the function, once a function is made `virtual` the function will *always* be `virtual`.

So to answer your question: Yes it's possible to use `Derived2::method1` through polymorphism. The code you show should work fine.